# JS: armazenar valores sorteados em array

Tags: javascript, array, random

Boa noite. Estou construindo um Bingo com Javascript e quero armazenar os números já sorteados numa array para depois consultá-la e evitar repetições, mas não sei como fazer isso. Alguém pode ajudar, por favor?

O código está assim:

```
<script>
sorteados = [99]
function getBingo() {
    var bola = Math.floor(Math.random() * (75 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    sorteados.push(bola);

    if (bola < 16) {
    letra = "B";
    }
    else {
        if (bola < 31) {
        letra = "I";
        }
        else {
            if (bola < 46) {
            letra = "N";
            }
            else {
                if (bola < 61) {
                letra = "G";
                }
                else {
                    if (bola < 76) {
                    letra = "O";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("bolinha").innerHTML = "<span style='color:yellow'>" +letra +"</span>&nbsp;"+ bola;
    document.getElementById(bola).innerHTML = "<span style='color:red; background-color:white; border-radius:20px; padding:2px;'>" + bola + "</span><audio src='"+bola+".mp3' autoplay></audio>";
}
</script>

<script>document.write ("Números já sorteados: "+sorteados.join(", ")); </script>
```

O jogo está rodando em https://monono.com.br/bingo

Aceito sugestões de melhorias.

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite, Roberto. Logo após você sortear um número verifique se existe algum numero idêntico no array "sorteados", se existir, você executa a função getBingo() novamente (isso se chama recursividade, quando você chama a função dentro dela mesma) e obtém outro numero, e faz a mesma verificação, caso ele não exista no array, voce adiciona ele com o .push e continua com o resto da função. Outra dica: ao invés de usar um if dentro de um else, basta usar "else if(condição){}". Gostei bastante do layout da sua aplicação, parabéns. :)

```
function getBingo() {
  var bola = Math.floor(Math.random() * (75 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
  let indice;
  for (indice = 0; indice < 99; indice++) {
    if(sorteados[indice] == bola) {
      getBingo();
    }
  }
  sorteados.push(bola);
  console.log(...sorteados)
  if (bola < 16) {
    letra = "B";
  }
    else if (bola < 31){ 
      letra = "I";
    }
      else if (bola < 46) {
        letra = "N";
      }
        else if (bola < 61) {
          letra = "G";
        }
          else if (bola < 76) {
            letra = "O";
          }
}
```

Comment: Isso está com cara de loop infinito. Você tentou rodar essa função? Execute ela duas vezes.

Comment: sim, me enganei usando aquele else dentro do for. obrigado! :D

Comment: Obrigado, João, mas o que não estou conseguindo fazer é alimentar a array com as bolas sorteadas.

Answer (score 0):

O método [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) do javascript parece se adequar melhor para o que pretende.

```
//...
let sorteados = [99];

function getBingo() {

  let bola = Math.floor(Math.random() * (75 - 1 + 1)) + 1;

  /*
   O método find () retorna o valor do primeiro elemento na 
   matriz (Array) que satisfaz a função de teste fornecida. Caso contrário, 
   undefined é retornado
   */

  let existeBola = sorteados.find(item => item === bola);

  if (existeBola) { 
    getBingo(); // Tenta novamente
    return;
  }

  sorteados.push(bola);

  if (bola < 16) {
    letra = "B";
  } else {
    if (bola < 31) {
      letra = "I";
    } else {
      if (bola < 46) {
        letra = "N";
      } else {
        if (bola < 61) {
          letra = "G";
        } else {
          if (bola < 76) {
            letra = "O";
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  //...

}
```

**Já agora aconselho vivamente a considerar uma condição de desistência (paragem da repitição) caso ele não encontre nenhuma bola não sorteado.**

**EX:**

```
//...
let sorteados = [99];
let max_tentativas = 10; // Numero maximo aceitavel de tentativas;
let tentativas = 0;

function getBingo() {

  let bola = Math.floor(Math.random() * (75 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
  let existeBola = sorteados.find(item => item === bola);

  if (existeBola) {

    if (tentativas < max_tentativas) { // 

      getBingo(); // Tenta novamente

    } else {

      alert('Atingiu o numero maximo de tentativas');
      // ...
    }

    tentativas++;

    return; // Para tudo aqui
  }

  sorteados.push(bola);
  tentativas = 0; // Zera o numero de tentativas ja feitas

  if (bola < 16) {
    letra = "B";
  } else {
    if (bola < 31) {
      letra = "I";
    } else {
      if (bola < 46) {
        letra = "N";
      } else {
        if (bola < 61) {
          letra = "G";
        } else {
          if (bola < 76) {
            letra = "O";
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  //...

}
```

Comment: Obrigado, Cristiano, vou testar suas sugestões.

Answer (score 0):

Melhor que ver se sorteou repetido e sortear de novo é usar um algoritmo diferente, tipo o [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) que lhe randomiza o array, e depois você apenas retira elementos do inicio, com a garantia que são únicos.

Exemplo:

```js
//função para baralhar os elementos do array
function shuffle(array) {
  let tamanho = array.length, temp, i;
  while (tamanho) {
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * tamanho--);
    temp = array[tamanho];
    array[tamanho] = array[i];
    array[i] = temp;
  }
  return array;
}

const QTD_BOLAS = 75, LETRAS = "BINGO";
let bolas = []; //criar o array para as bolas
for (let i = 1;i <= QTD_BOLAS; ++i){
  bolas.push(i); //inserir as bolas disponiveis
}
shuffle(bolas);

document.getElementById("sortear").addEventListener("click", function(){
  let bolaSorteada = bolas.shift(); //retirar a primeira bola do array
  let bolasPorLetra = QTD_BOLAS / LETRAS.length; 
  let letra = LETRAS[Math.floor((bolaSorteada - 1) / bolasPorLetra)]; //obter a letra escolhida
  console.log("Sorteada - " + letra + bolaSorteada);
});
```

```html
<button id="sortear">Sortear</button>
```

Note que substitui os `ifs` que tinha para descobrir a letra por uma lógica diferente. Neste código, ele assume que existem X bolas para cada letra, dividindo a quantidade de bolas que existem pela quantidade de letras, que no caso vai dar 15 letras por bola. O que significa que se dividir a bola sorteada por 15, da-lhe a posição da letra a mostrar, o que torna o código mais direto e menos repetitivo.

Exemplo:

- Se sair a bola 10, ao dividir por 15 resulta em 0 o que lhe dá a primeira letra da palavra `"BINGO"` o `"B"`.
- Se sair a bola 20, ao dividir por 15 resulta em 1 o que lhe dá a segunda letra da palavra `"BINGO"` o `"I"`.

Se quiser pode também evitar que o usuário sorteie bolas se já saíram todas, verificando o tamanho do array `bolas` antes de sortear, algo como `if (bolas.length > 0)`.